# Is there a way to include XAML files in another XAML file?

Tags: xaml

I want to create a master XAML file which includes a bunch of other XAML files. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean as a composite application?  You can use "UserControls", but I'm not sure I'm answering your question.  Can you clarify?

Comment: Images are built dynamically from each ControlTemplate. I need to aggregate all ControlTemplate into a single one using something like an "include" to link to other ControlTemplates. The goal is to render all images defined in the multiple ControlTemplates as a single css-sprite. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 0):

In your main Xaml, use a **ItemsControl** balise and for the Xaml composant, you must define your project with **UserControl** in place of **Window**

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Plugins" x:FieldModifier="private" Height="auto">
```

In your code, you just need to write this:

```
Plugins.Items.Add(UserControl);
```

Maybe you can learn something about MEF for the loading of all yours Xaml